# Pytest in Azure pipeline does not see specific files?

Tags: python, pytest, azure-pipelines

I have a `src` directory which contains a `pyproject.toml`, right next to my `setup.py` (which I *can* find, for a fact).

But when I run the task

```
- bash: pytest -c src/pyproject.toml
  displayName: Run tests
  workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
```

I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/src/pyproject.toml'`.

Everything works fine without trying to point to this file from pytest. Why? The same setup works fine locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `workingDirectory` should be `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`, not `$(Pipeline.Workspace)`.

The `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` is the local path on the agent where **all folders for a given build pipeline are created**.

The `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` is the local path on the agent **where your source code files are downloaded**.

Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug) for detailed information about predefined variables in Azure DevOps